# Spring Data MongoDb bean xml configuration for repository interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

I have an existing spring application using `xml` configuration.
Now, I will be using `spring-data-mongodb` to connect it to a Mongo database.
My `repository/dao` are all interfaces like:

```
public interface CustomerDao extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {
   ...
}
```

and inside my service class `CustomerService` it autowires `CustomerDao` interface.

```
<bean id="customerDao" class="com.myapp.repository.CustomerDao" />
<bean id="customerService" class="com.myapp.service.CustomerService">
    <property name="customerDao" ref="customerDao"/>
</bean>
```

but since `CustomerDao` is an interface, I am always getting the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.myapp.repository.CustomerDao]: Specified class is an interface
```

Based on the tutorials for `spring-data-mongodb` repositories are mostly interfaces extending to `MongoRepository`.

My problem is that, I am getting error when autowiring `CustomerDao` inside `CustomerService` class if I will not create a bean entry in the `xml` configuration. Below is the error I am getting:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.repository.CustomerDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=customerDao)}
```

Comment: Have you added @Repository on CustomerDao??

Comment: Yeah, I did but still I got the same error

Answer (score 1):

You can just [specify repositories package location](https://github.com/azee/quack/blob/master/dal/src/main/resources/dal-context.xml#L26) (and custom implementations, if needed).

Then you can [just create an interface](https://github.com/azee/quack/blob/master/dal/src/main/java/ru/greatbit/quack/dal/AttributeRepository.java) extending one of the mongo-spring-data repositories (I prefer PagingAndSortignRepository)

After that you'll be able to [Autowire](https://github.com/azee/quack/blob/master/services/src/main/java/ru/greatbit/quack/services/LaunchService.java#L20) your repos.

Don't forget to check [component scan package](https://github.com/azee/quack/blob/master/dal/src/main/resources/dal-context.xml#L13) - your repos and services should be there.

And the last thing - check for [Spring annotations](https://github.com/azee/quack/blob/master/services/src/main/java/ru/greatbit/quack/services/LaunchService.java#L16) on your services